# Change field to a returnable local variable in if statement

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, arguments

Ok. So here's the situation. I have a calculateTax method in my class as you can see below.

But I realize that I have made a big mistake. The "tax" has actually been created as a field at the start of the class.

`private double   tax;`

This should actually be a variable!

But when I create it as a local variable in the method `public double calculateTax(double tax)` it works, but when I run my tests against it they fail. I get the message

`The method calculateTax(double) in the type Salary is not applicable for the arguments ()`

So where am I going wrong?

How can I create the tax variable (which can still be returned) without changing the name of the method? The method "calculateTax" needs to stay as that. So where and how can I create the "tax" variable? Thanks in advance!

```
public double calculateTax() {

if (this.salary <= personalAllowance) { // If the salary is less
  // £9440 (personal allowance) and below then no tax will be applied.

}

else if (this.salary <= taxThreshold) { // Else if the salary is less than or equal to the
  // tax threshold then do the following:
  double taxableSalary = this.salary - personalAllowance; // Salary take away the personal allowance
  // equals the taxable salary.
  this.tax = taxableSalary * 0.2; // The tax equal the taxable salary * 0.2 (20%)
}

else if (this.salary > 32010) {

  double basicRate = taxThreshold * 0.2; // The basic rate tax is the tax threshold * 0.2
  double difference = this.salary - taxThreshold; // The difference is the salary - the tax threshold
  double highTax = difference - personalAllowance; // The high tax to be calculated is the difference
  // take away personal allowance.
  double highRate = highTax * 0.4; // The high rate tax is the high tax * the high tax value (40%)

  this.tax = highRate + basicRate; // Total tax is the high rate tax (40%) + the basic rate tax (20%)

}
return tax;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tax variable is fine.

The compiler thinks that your `calculateTax()` method expects an argument, a double, representing salary.  (I think - maybe the tax rate?)  e.g.  `calculateTax(56789.12)`;

I don't see that in the code you posted but something is incomplete.